# Time complexity on nested for loop

Tags: time-complexity

```
function(n): 
{
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n / 2; j++)
            output("")
    }
}
```

Now I have calculated the time complexity for the first for loop which is **O(n)**. Now the second for loop shows `j <= n / 2` so any given `n` I put, for example, a range of `[1,2,...,10]` will give me **O(log(n))** since it will continuously give me a series of `n`,`n/2`,`n/4`,`n/8` .... `K`.

So if we wanted to compare the relationship it must look something like this `2^n = k`.

My question is will it give me **O(log(n))**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not give you `o(logn)`.
The first for loop is `O(n)`. The second loop is `O(n)` as well, as the number of iterations grows as a function of `n` (the growth rate is linear).
It would be the same even by changing the second loop to something like

```
for (j=1; j<=n/2000; j++)
```

or in general if you replace the denominator with any constant `k`.
To conclude, the time compexity is quadratic, i.e., `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 3):

The correct summation according to the code is:

[image: 1]

So, it's not `O(log n)`. It's `O(n^2)`.